# How to prevent dropdown menu from retracting when trying to scroll

Tags: css, menu, scrollable

I have what are supposed to be scrollable menus for desktop and mobile. However, when you pull down the sidebar and release — the whole menu retracts. You can't open the menu and just scroll.

How do I prevent the main menu from retracting so the user can easily scroll?

```
.nav li ul {
max-height: 550px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}

Comment: You should post all of your code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is all of my code. Everything else is built into the theme. The CSS used to allow scrolling. Now it just shows the scroll bar and retracts when you drag the handle but doesn't scroll. Without it, it's just one long drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Reducing the height from 550 to 450 allows the dropdown menu to scroll.

```
.nav li ul {
max-height: 450px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}